# How can I disable the Flutter slider class to prevent a user from moving it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm hoping to render a flutter slider that is unmovable, meaning that I hope to pass the slider an initial value that the user will not be able to change purely for UI visualization?

Has anyone had any experience locking this slider in place?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 24):

Give it a value and then set the `onChanged:` property to null.

```
onChanged: null
```

This disables the Slider.

Otherwise, you could give `max:` and `min:` the same value. In this case, though, the slider is not greyed out but it stays at zero.

Comment: Thanks, chemamolins: the problem as you alluded to is that if I pass a null value it stays grey. If I pass the same value as max and min, it stays at zero, which also doesn't capture what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Just wrap an AbsorbPointer around your slider like so:

```
AbsorbPointer(
            child: Slider(
              onChanged: (value) => print(value),
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              divisions: 10,
              value: 30,
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to have your `SliderTheme` affect a disabled slider you have to overwrite the `disabled` attributes.

Here is a quick example:

```
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
    disabledActiveTrackColor: Colors.red[700],
    disabledInactiveTrackColor: Colors.red[100],
    disabledThumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
  ),
  child: Slider(
    value: 0.2,
    onChanged: null,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the slider as 'active' with a single value, but not allow the user to change it, use an empty function

```
  return Slider(
    max: 20,
    value: 10,
    onChanged: (double value) {}, // not allowing seek, but shows as active color
  );
```

Similarly, to show the progress but not allow the user to change the value

```
double myUpdatingProgressValue = (update this every build() invocation)

return Slider(
    max: 20,
    value: myUpdatingProgressValue,
    onChanged: (double value) {}, // not allowing seek, but shows as active color
  );
```

For either of above scenarios, use `onChanged: null` for showing the inactive (usually gray) color.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SliderTheme:

```
SliderTheme(data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                                  disabledThumbColor:
                                      Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                  disabledActiveTrackColor:
                                      Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                              child: Slider(
                                divisions: 10,
                                max: 100,
                                value: 10,
                                onChanged: null,
                              ),
                            )
```

Answer (score -1):

The same more detailed:

```
var _onChanged;
if (someVariable) {
  _onChanged = (value) => print(value);
}

child: Slider(
  onChanged: _onChanged,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  divisions: 10,
  value: 30,
),
```